# Use SELECT statements as value to insert

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`table_3` (
`value_id` ,
`entity_type_id` ,
`attribute_id` ,
`store_id` ,
`entity_id` ,
`value`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '4',  '85',  '0',  
SELECT entity_id FROM table_3 WHERE table_3.value = 'someTextThatIKnow',  
SELECT value FROM table_1 WHERE entity_id = SELECT entity_id FROM table_3 WHERE table_3.value = 'someTextThatIKnow'
);
```

That's the code that I have. So, in `table_3` I have an inserted row, which has values for `entity_id` and `value` columns. Now, in the same table I want to insert in the same columns the following:

1. in `entity_id` -> the same value as from the already inserted row
2. in `value` -> the value from a row in `table_1` (which also has *entity_id* and *value* columns) where under `entity_id` the value is the same as the row in `table_3`.

I hope you can understand what my idea is.

Now, I am getting Error `#1064` (syntax error). I can seem to find any syntax errors. I also tried surrounding the table names with `' '`. How can I construct this query?

Comment: If you have to enclose use `()` however the answers given below are by far better.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you're trying to add more, entirely new rows to table_3, not update existing rows to put missing data from table_1 in a column, right?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, note that there is no requirement to enclose integers in inverted commas. Doing so *can* slow down performance!

Comment: @Strawberry you call single quotes "inverted commas"? ... just looked seems to be UK thing?

Comment: @DigitalChris Yes. For some reason the colonies have adopted other expressions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the values bit, and put all the data in your select:

```
INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`table_3` (
`value_id` ,
`entity_type_id` ,
`attribute_id` ,
`store_id` ,
`entity_id` ,
`value`
)
SELECT NULL, 4, 85, 0, table_3.entity_id, table_1.value 
FROM table_3 
INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_3.entity_id = table_1.entity_id
WHERE table_3.value = 'someTextThatIKnow';
```

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html). Note that this may insert more than a single row at a time.

---

Per follow-up from the comments:

For adding three entries in table_3, with three different entity_type_id values, but only a single matching existing row, you can call the insert statement as above three times, with three different hard coded values.

Or, you can do it in a single batch like this:

```
INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`table_3` (
`value_id` ,
`entity_type_id` ,
`attribute_id` ,
`store_id` ,
`entity_id` ,
`value`
)
SELECT NULL, 4, entid_values.entity_type_id, 0, table_3.entity_id, table_1.value 
FROM table_3 
INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_3.entity_id = table_1.entity_id
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT 85 AS entity_type_id
  UNION
  SELECT 86 AS entity_type_id
  UNION
  SELECT 87 AS entity_type_id
) AS entid_values
WHERE table_3.value = 'someTextThatIKnow';
```

It's also possible to accomplish this by creating, populating, and cross joining against a temporary table, rather than using a nested query. The temp table approach would make the insert statement easier to read if you use many different hard coded values, or wanted to apply multiple static values for several different columns.

An easier to read and better performing way to do this, since they're integer values, would be to keep [a tally or numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) in your database and join against that.

Comment: Why does it have the chance to insert more than a single row, whereas the rows from which I take the input value are existent only once?

Comment: If the data matching the select statement exists only once, then it will only insert one row. But it has the potential to insert more than one, because you're using a select statement, which selects a set of rows. For example, if there are three rows in table_3 with value = 'someTextThatIKnow' and row in table_1 with a matching entity_id, then this query would insert three rows.

Comment: I see. But, yeah, the match between the value that I select and the entity_id happens only once, so it's all good in the hood.

Comment: Is it possible to execute this query for 3 rows at once, where the difference will be only the 3rd value -> `85`, `86`, `87`? 
Because it looks kinda' robust to execute the `INSERT` 3 times...

Comment: You mean insert three rows with three different entity_type_id values but all other data the same, and using the same select statement? This would require a bit more work - either three insert statements or a join against a temp table or a union to get the hard coded values. Please confirm that I've not misunderstood what you're asking and I'll edit an example in to my answer.

Comment: Yes - three rows with three different `entity_type_id` values, but all other data the same. If you do this - please, can you add the code bellow the already existing one (instead of editing it). I think it would be better if the current code stays, because it is directly related to the asked question itself. :) Thank you very much for your help and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Put all the values to insert into the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO  `database_name`.`table_3` (
`value_id` ,
`entity_type_id` ,
`attribute_id` ,
`store_id` ,
`entity_id` ,
`value`)

SELECT NULL ,  '4',  '85',  '0',  t3.entity_id, t1.value
FROM table_3 t3
INNER JOIN table_1 t1 ON t3.entity_id = t1.entity_id
WHERE t3.value = 'someTextThatIKnow';
```

Comment: but you don't use `table_1` anywhere, and that's where I must take the input value that I want to insert in `table_3`